# Genymotion - Plugin is not available in Eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse, emulation, genymotion

I am trying to use Genymotion Emulator to speedup the development. I installed **Genymostion** along with **Virtual Box**.

But when I am trying to download plugin

> via help -> install new software -> add this link:
>   http://plugins.genymotion.com/eclipse

Its showing **There are no categorized item** as in below Image.

[image]

Comment: You dont need a plugin to use genymotion, just open genymotion independently from your installed folder, then when you run your project in choose device to run on you should be able to see your virtual device

Comment: my suggestion is switch to Android Stduio

Comment: @Nilesh working with phonegap application. is it possible to develop with Android studio

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Clear the 'Group items by category' check box near the bottom of that 'Install New Software' dialog. You should then see 'Genymotion Eclipse Tools'.

Answer (score 0):

Some problem in http://plugins.genymotion.com/eclipse url.

So use manual method to install plugin in Eclipse

**Manual install genymotion plugin :**

1. download jar file from this link : http://plugins.genymotion.com/plugins/idea/1.0.6/genymotion-idea-plugin-20150929.jar

2.Follow the steps corresponding to your operating system:

**Windows**

- If you have administrator rights, put the **.jar** archive in the
  **Plugins** directory of the Eclipse installation folder.
- Without administrator rights, put the **.jar** archive in the
  **Plugins** directory of the **Local Settings\Eclipse** folder.

**Mac OS X**

- With administrator rights, put the **.jar** archive in the **Plugins**
  directory of the Eclipse installation folder.

**Linux**

- If you have administrator rights, put the **.jar** archive in the Plugins
  directory of the **Eclipse** installation folder.
- Without administrator rights, put the **.jar** archive in the Plugins
  directory of the    `/home/<user>/Eclipse` folder.

Comment: There is no problem with the URL, it is just that the plugin is not 'categorized'

Answer (score 0):

The old URL for genymotion plugin in eclipse i.e  http://plugins.genymotion.com/eclipse seems to be not working.

So you may add the latest URL i.e http or https://dl.genymotion.com/eclipse

By clicking on Help --> Install New Software and pasting the URL and for sure your problem will be resolved.

**And also please make sure to uncheck the 'Group items by category' checkbox.**

**Good Luck :)**